Where did I go wrong in using Kirchhoff's Voltage Law for this circuit?
I stumbled upon this question from my little brother's high school textbook:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Where the question is the current through R5. I tried simplifying the circuit into a single loop first before using the properties of resistors in parallel (\$I_1 : I_2 : I_3 : \dotsm : I_N = \frac{1}{R_1} : \frac{1}{R_2} : \frac{1}{R_3} : \dotsm : \frac{1}{R_N}\$) and easy enough, I found it to be \$I = 0.66... \mathrm{\ A}\$.
However, apparently, my brother's problem was when he tried to simplify the circuit into a two-loop circuit and using Kirchoff's Law like so:

simulate this circuit
So, to correct his work while also proving that my method is nevertheless correct, I tried applying KCL to his two-loop circuit.
I'm using his textbook's rule in applying KVL here:
$$
\begin{aligned}
21I_1 + 4.8I_3 &= 100 &&\textrm{Loop I (clockwise)}\\
24I_2 + 4.8I_3 &= 0 &&\textrm{Loop II (clockwise)} \\
I_1 &= I_2 + I_3 
\end{aligned}
$$
From the above equations, I get \$I_3 \approx 4,63 \textrm{ A}\$ which is clearly wrong, but I don't know where.

R1 R2 and R3 are not in parallel - the generator counts!. So your initial proportion is not correct. Have you tried to simulate it?

Yes, I am aware, and the simulation result aligned with my first method. My initial method is 1) adding R4+R5 into R'', 2) calculating R2||R3 into R', 3) calculating R'||R'' into R''', making the circuit a single loop.

Could you please mark the currents in the circuit? It's impossible to revise it without knowing which currents you are calling I1, I2... and which direction you took.

basically, the generator sees R1 in series with R2//R3//(R4+R5), numerically 25Ω, which means it is providing 4A of current. I do not know where your 0.66A come from (nor which current is supposed to be...)

edited schematics

@Rmano Yes, the current through the voltage source is 4A. However, the question is about the current through the R5 = 20Ω, which I found to be 0.667A, all in agreement with the simulation.

You've swapped $I_2$ and $I_3$ in your two KVL equations

Ah, right. Edited schematics again. Sorry, I'm not familiar with CircuitLab

The error is in the "Loop II" equation. It's
$$24I_3-4.8I_2=0$$
(notice the sign). You can also feel it was the problem (now that the currents are correctly marked). In your equation, the only possible solution has I₂ and I₃ of opposite signs, which is unphysical.
If you are unsure, a trick is to mark the voltage drops:

notice that when exploring the loop, your cyan "path" enters the resistors at opposite voltages, so their signs must be opposite.
Solution in sympy:
In [6]: import sympy as sym
In [7]: from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve
In [8]: i1,i2,i3=sym.symbols("I_1, I_2, I_3")
In [9]: linsolve([21*i1+4.8*i3-100, 24*i2-4.8*i3, i1-i2-i3],[i1,i2,i3])
Out[9]: {(4.0, 0.666666666666667, 3.33333333333333)}


Well, I just named it after the example in his textbook.
I think the problem showed up when I tried to follow his textbook guide to applying KVL (there may be some error in translation):

If the current has the same direction as the loop, it has a positive sign, and vice versa.
When traversing through the loop, if we found the negative terminal of the voltage source before its positive terminal, then the emf given by the source has a positive sign, and vice versa.
All resistance has a positive sign.


No, that description is wrong. "All resistances have positive signs" is impossible, given that the current direction is arbitrary.

In accordance with passive sign convention, you must remember that resistors have the higher potential at the end where current enters. That means as you go around loop II, potential falls as you traverse one resistor, and rises as you traverse the other:
$$ -4.8I_3 + 24I_2 = 0 $$
or
$$ 4.8I_3 - 24I_2 = 0 $$
As a precaution, it's always good to label voltage polarities too, which helps avoid these mistakes:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As long as your annotations of voltage polarity across resistors (and capacitors and inductors) conforms (as per passive sign convention) with current direction through them, then your thinking can go like this: Travelling clockwise around loop I, from say X, first I traverse R1 and encounter a fall in potential (to subtract), then V1 which incurs a rise (add). Lastly I jump across R6 after which potential has fallen again (subtract), back to what it was at the start, for zero net change:
$$ -I_1R_1 + 100 -I_3R_6 = 0 $$

Oops, we crossed edits. Sorry. Yes, this is the same way I teach it --- I think that the "fad" of separating active and passive component  is at least useless and normally dangerous.

@Rmano It's a hazard! Unavoidable, so no worries
